# buddypress groups geo location

Tags: php, wordpress, location, buddypress, geo

Been googling for hours and can't find the solution to my problem. Basically what I need to do is display the buddypress groups by ip or using geo location, like if I am from Alabama when I logged in I will be seeing the group called "Alabama Group" and no one else. And this goes on for different location as they will be presented in a group.
I've search for plugins but I don't know how to use them in groups nor they can be used in buddypress, I think an if statement would do the trick but not sure how to do the rest of the IP's.

What do guys think is the best  way to handle this? Thanks!